# Why can't RPM find dependencies, although they are installed?

Tags: rpm, dependencies

Im' trying to rpm -ivh an RPM package.
The install fails, saying that php53 dependencies are failing.

However, I installed these packages in that very same version, so I don't understand why rpm doesn't find them :

```
[xxxx@localhost 02.00.00]$ sudo rpm -ivh product-02.00.00.x86_64.rpm 
[sudo] password for xxxx: 
error: Failed dependencies:
    php53 >= 5.3.3 is needed by product-02.00.00-932.x86_64
    php53-cli >= 5.3.3 is needed by product-02.00.00-932.x86_64
    php53-common >= 5.3.3 is needed by product-02.00.00-932.x86_64
    php53-xml >= 5.3.3 is needed by product-02.00.00-932.x86_64
    [xxxx@localhost 02.00.00]$ rpm -qa | grep "php"
php-xml-5.3.3-3.el6_2.8.x86_64
php-5.3.3-3.el6_2.8.x86_64
php-common-5.3.3-3.el6_2.8.x86_64
php-cli-5.3.3-3.el6_2.8.x86_64
```

This is about a RedHat 6.3. The RPM to be installed was generated on RedHat 6.3 as well.

Comment: You wouldn't by any chance be trying to install a package intended for an RHEL5 system (with php53) on an RHEL6 system (or equivalent, eg CentOS), would you?

Comment: And you postgresql server version, is that the same? Basically more info please!

Comment: @Danie : Yes, sorry. I stopped at the first step. I instaleld postgresql 9.2 and now rpm only complains with php.

Comment: @MadHatter : No, I generated the RPM on a RHEL 6.3 box as well.

Comment: @Danie : Well, this is awkward, but actually you are right. I started development under RHEL 5.6. At that time the php packages were names php53-cli etc... Now, in RHEL 6 these packages are names php-cli etc... Submit an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments we received we can deduce the following,

- Make sure your RPM build environment matches that of your production server. This will help with package name dependancies and troubleshooting issues. If you cannot update the build server make sure that the rpm spec file points to the correct package names, etc.
- Remember that package names differ between major centos versions! :)

Regards,
Danie

Comment: The "Remember that package names differ between major centos versions! :)" did the trick : PHP packages names changed... Thx !